# What are virtual and apparent forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, terminology, definition

Acceleration in a rotating frame can be written as: $$\underline{a}=\frac{\partial^2\underline{r}}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial\underline{\omega}}{\partial t}\times\underline{r}+2\underline{\omega}\times\frac{\partial\underline{r}}{\partial t}+\underline{\omega}\times(\underline{\omega}\times\underline{r})$$ My lecturer referred to $\frac{\partial^2\underline{r}}{\partial t^2}$ as apparent acceleration and $\frac{\partial\underline{\omega}}{\partial t}\times\underline{r}+2\underline{\omega}\times\frac{\partial\underline{r}}{\partial t}+\underline{\omega}\times(\underline{\omega}\times\underline{r})$ as virtual acceleration but I am unsure as to what this means and was hoping somebody could help explain.

Answer (score 0):

Apparent forces are those that show up as a result of an accelerating reference frame, i.e., they are not forces over the system, but an effect of being in a reference system over which a force IS being applied. Therefore, if you accelerate in an accelerating reference frame, you would start already with some "virtual" acceleration.